# How to find nonlinear conductance?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, computational-physics, software, non-linear-optics

For quantum transport at the level of linear response, there is the Landauer-Buttiker formula. And for tight-binding models, there are programs targeting such calculations, such as the [kwant](https://kwant-project.org/) package.

However, what about the situation for nonlinear responses at finite frequencies? Is there any established theory/method or even programs? I'm particularly interested in the $2\omega$ second harmonics generation in tight-binding models, which is generated, e.g., by applying a bias voltage/current of frequency $\omega$.

Comment: Could you please clarify the scenario you are asking for? Is bias voltage time-periodic in your case, or do you have external elec. and mag. fields? Also, LB is not limited to linear response level in the sense that bias voltage is the „external field“ (see resanant level model in the book by Haug and Jauho).

Comment: @RudolfSmorka Updated. Either of them. I think they are probably closely related?

Comment: I'd say these two scenarios are very different. Applying a time-dependent bias requires the description of a fermionic bath (the leads), which is why one has to solve the Dyson equation for nonequilibrium Green functions (from which you can derive the Landauer-Büttiker formula for the current). If there are only classical fields in your model, without leads, then you can simply solve the time-dep. Schrödinger equation for the finite tight binding chain, e.g. using a RK4 integrator, without having to deal with the subtleties of how to include the fermionic bath.

Comment: @RudolfSmorka Thank you for the explanation. Then I think I'm actually more interested in the former.

Comment: There are a lot of works in non-linear transport. Some works use the Boltzmann transport, for example see https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.95.155421. There is also diagrammatic approach to calculate the same. This is developed in https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.99.045121. They also address second harmonics here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned about existing programs. For time-dependent quantum transport at the single-particle level, there is [tkwant](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/abddf7/meta).

If you are interested in writing your own code (since every existing package has its limitations, obviously), then its useful to stepwise increase the complexity of the approach necessary for what your specific research question is.

For a lattice not coupled to leads but exposed to external fields, for example described by Peierls-substituted tight-binding model

$$H = -\sum_{i,j}t\mathrm{e}^{-i\int_{R_i}^{R_j} A(r)\mathrm{d}r}c_i^\dagger c_j^{\phantom{\dagger}},$$

one can do exact diagonalization or solve the time-dependent Schrödinger equation with a simple integrator, e.g. RK4, quite easily for very large system sizes. Note that I am assuming that you are working on the single-particle level.

For an open quantum system, the situation is different. However, other people in the field have derived nice results some time ago. One approach, which is numerically exact and has been rigorously derived, and can deal with time-dependent system and bath Hamiltonians is the hierarchical equation of motion approach, e.g. as formulated in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0243.pdf) and [this one](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/128/23/234703/70874/Exact-dynamics-of-dissipative-electronic-systems?redirectedFrom=fulltext) for the single-particle density matrix. It has been shown in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.75.195127) that the HEOM approach can be formulated equivalently using Keldysh nonequilibrium Green functions. I have it implemented for my own research, so if you're interested we can chat about it.

Edit: Note, that these approaches I mentioned above do not give you the second-harmonic you asked for straight-forwardly. But you can compute, in principle, any single-particle observable you are interested in.

Comment: Doesn't tkwant, which relies on kwant, treat linear response only? Or I misunderstand?

Comment: Why do you think so? They use an approach related to time-dependent NEGF (though they don't implement the Green functions directly, but instead work with scattering wavefunctions instead).

Comment: Yes, but kwant treats linear response only. It only deals with infinitesimal bias for differential conductance. Hence I suspect the same for tkwant.

Comment: Ok, I see. In their tkwant paper I did not find any statement clarifying this, and I am not sure about this either.

Comment: Does the HEOM method you mentioned work for the case with applied oscillating bias? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. The bias does not have to be periodic even, it can have any arbitrary time dependence.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds good. I've never heard of it. So given a noninteracting tight-binding system with some applied periodic bias, what is needed to get the second-harmonic response from that method? Also, does it take into account effects due to surface state (which is desired)?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea about second-harmonic generation, sorry for that. The only thing I wanted to mention is that there exist methods to treat the time-dependent quantum transport problem exactly on a single-particle level. You probably have some working definition for the response function. How does it look like? Can you obtain it from the reduced density matrix or the dynamics thereof (e.g. Fourier-transform of dynamics of some observable)?